# use create-react-native-app without expo-cli

Tags: react-native, expo, create-react-native-app

I have set up `create-react-native-app` as said in the `react` native docs. If my project name is `proj`, according to the docs, the commands to be run should be :

```
create-react-native-app proj
cd proj
npm start
```

But when I run `create-react-native-app`, I get a menu to select a blank template or the one with tabs. And instead of `npm` start, it says to use expo start. Why am I getting a different output compared to the docs?

Comment: official documentation is quite different, https://github.com/react-community/create-react-native-app#quick-overview. Where did you get those steps?

Comment: @Rod.C here https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html

Comment: I guess Facebook documentation is outdated, create-react-native-app is a script created by the community, is not an official script form Facebook. I can be wrong, but I added some links below, so you can follow the official documentation that has different steps, and the 'eject' process if you don't want to use expo

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Official documentation indicates different steps:
https://github.com/react-community/create-react-native-app#create-react-native-app

if you don't want to use Expo, just follow the eject steps:
https://github.com/react-community/create-react-native-app/blob/master/EJECTING.md. Optionally you can reate

or you can create a react native app by yourself without using the create-react-native-app script. More details here, https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html#creating-a-new-application

Comment: You are right. Once I saw the name Facebook, I didn't go to research about that topic any further. Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 14):

You can use:

```
react-native init projectName
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the executable react-native package. This will not require you to install react-native as a global dependency:

`npx react-native init yourProjectName`